# Accessing Subdomain in Rails3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, subdomain

I'm working to get into my model a request for the subdomain.

So basically I have a habtm association, which I need to ask, if my subdomain is found in the association. 
So in the user model -

```
def subdomain
  "subdomain"
end

def owner
   self.accounts.find_by_subdomain(subdomain)
end
```

If it is found, then I have permission to do stuff as the subdomain owner. 
But no matter how I can't figure out how to have the model access the subdomain

So basically I'm not sure how to pull "subdomain" from the controller / URI into the model. 
Thanks!

Comment: A little bit more info - Basically I a user (devise) current_user, and if she is on her domain - e.g.  submarine.mydomain.com . I want to allow here to moderate /add / edit all the documents, associated with that domain. But if she goes to plane.mydomain.com I don't want to give here owner access. 
So it is a bit more complex than just in cancan assigning - user.admin?  But I'm a bit loss at how to go about this? 
How can I create a user.owner  for this whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller (or views for that matter) you can use something like `request.host.split('.')[0]` to get the host and parse out the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was having trouble getting that request.host.split... or request.subdomain.... to work in my model. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing `request` from your model, it should be happening in your controller. You would pass the subdomain to the model in the controller, after you've gotten it from `request`. then model.subdomain would work, assuming you've stored the subdomain somewhere.